# Typesafe Primary Key in Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, orm, jpa

I am looking for a way to have a typesafe primary key for my entities using generics in Hibernate.  Instead of doing this

```
@Entity
public class User{

@PrimaryKey
Long id

}
```

I was thinking of doing this...

```
@Entity
public class User{

@PrimaryKey
PrimaryKey<User,Long> id

}
```

Or take the type inference even further...

Any ideas?  Has anybody ever tried this before?  Would you do this by making your  class PrimaryKey embeddable?

```
@Entity
public class User extends MyEntity<Long>//Primary key type{

@PrimaryKey
PrimaryKey<User> id;

}
```

Comment: There can be used type converters instead of embedded types. But haven't tested approach

Comment: 7 years have passed, @Benju can you, please, share experience, have you used this eventually, and did it helped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is possible to use a PK class and to use it as a member of entities with the [`@EmbeddedId`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html), this would typically make all your JQL queries and your Java code more verbose:

```
select a.addressKey.id from Address a
```

or

```
AddressKey addressKey = new AddressKey();
addressKey.setCountry("USA");
addressKey.setId(634);
Address a = entityManager.find(Address.class, addressKey);
```

So I would personally use this for a real composite key (i.e. not with a single attribute) only.

Actually, I'm really wondering what problem you are trying to solve because at the end, you will have to deal with a `Long` anyway. I don't really see the added value of a single attribute typesafe primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a typesafe way to identify an entity, what about using its LazyLoadingProxy?